# ROBLOX: get a handler object in Touched function

Tags: roblox

I have a simple map with 2 gates (blue and red) and a ball.

I need a listener function for checking ball collisions with a gate.

I have created a server script:

```
function goal(hitter)
    if hitter.Name == "ball" then
        print(Instance.Parent)
        print(hitter)
        print("============")       
    end
end

game.Workspace.gate_blue.Touched:Connect(goal)
game.Workspace.gate_red.Touched:Connect(goal)
```

I need to detect in the function which gate has been hitted.

**How can I get the gate name in the function?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could reuse the `goal` functionality is to make a [higher-order function](https://typeofnan.dev/what-is-a-higher-order-function/) :

```
function onGoalTouched(goalName)
    return function(hitter)
        if hitter.Name == "ball" then
            print(Instance.Parent)
            print(hitter, goalName)
            print("============")       
        end
    end
end

local blueGate = game.Workspace.gate_blue
local redGate = game.Workspace.gate_red

blueGate.Touched:Connect(onGoalTouched(blueGate))
redGate.Touched:Connect(onGoalTouched(redGate))
```